# Reduce a sparse matrix in numpy

Tags: numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix

It seems that I am missing something very basic here.
I have a large square matrix which is mostly zeros. What I want is to reduce it to a matrix that contains all rows and columns with non-zero entries.
For example:

```
1 1 0 1
1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0
1 1 0 1
```

Should be reduced to:

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

Is there a fast way to do this?

Comment: What about rows/columns that have some nonzero and some zero entries? Keep them?

Comment: Yes, if there are any non-zero elements, they should be kept. I was thinking of slicing across different axes in sequence. First rows with all zeros, then columns with all zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
>>> arr
array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.]])

>>> mask = (arr==0)

arr = arr[~np.all(mask,axis=0)]
arr = arr[:,~np.all(mask,axis=1)]
>>> arr
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Two questions though. First off, why does not `mask=(arr!=0)` work (with `np.all` vs `~np.all`). Second, what is the mysterious `~` all about?

Comment: @Manbroski `~` is a shortcut to the bit-wise NOT operator, see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.invert.html). I would play with `np.all` and different masks to see why I wrote the operation as is, I am not sure I can succinctly put it into words.

Comment: It is a little hard to google special characters, which is why I was perplexed by the semantics of its usage. Many thanks.